# Primitives for the iphone with monogame

Tags: iphone, primitive, monogame

I am trying to draw some primitives with monogame. I am using the `GraphicsDevice` and the `DrawUserPrimitives` method. Although I can see the rectangle I am drawing in an Android device it is missing on the iPhone simulator. Am I missing something or is drawing primitives on the iPhone with monogame not supported?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using the (develop3D branch)[https://github.com/mono/MonoGame/tree/develop3d]?